# How to remove multiple instances of a specific value from array

Tags: php

I am trying to unset every instance of a specific value from my array, however I am only able to unset the first instance of that value. How can I remove everything where the value equals what I am searching for?

```
$toRemove = array("red","blue");
$myArray = array("red", "green", "blue", "blue", "blue", "purple", "yellow");

foreach ($toRemove as $remove)
{
    if (($key = array_search($remove, $myArray)) !== false)
    {
        unset($myArray[$key];
    }
}
print_r($myArray);
```

The above is only returning this as my array values:

```
array("green", "blue", "blue", "purple", "yellow");
```

Comment: See [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score 1):

Just compute the difference:

```
$myArray = array_diff($myArray, $toRemove);
```

However, your current code only returns one key so you would need to search for more.  You can use a `while`:

```
foreach ($toRemove as $remove)
{
    while (($key = array_search($remove, $myArray)) !== false)
    {
        unset($myArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Or get all of the keys and loop them:

```
foreach ($toRemove as $remove)
{
    foreach (array_keys($myArray, $remove) as $key)
    {
        unset($myArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason I was under the impression I couldn't update my original array using array_diff. This does what I need, will upvote when It allows me to. Thanks

Comment: Added a fix for your current code.